# Plotting PostgreSQL PostGIS points on map for web application

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

My goal is to create a web app where there's a map of a city and you can filter for year, month, day, etc. and crimes for that day will pop up as points on a map. I already have the data formatted as PostGIS objects in PostgreSQL, with the associated crime type and date, but I'm not sure how to go about creating the web app and querying the data on the front end.

I know that Python and possibly GeoDjango could be an option. I've also looked into gmplot. I want something that's dynamic and users could zoom in and click on individual data points to get some more information about the crime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many, many options for building an app like this.  A new option that is lightweight and powerful is `pg_tileserv` and `pg_featureserv`.  They connect directly to PostGIS and provide modern MVT and OGC Features API support.  You would probably need to write a custom function to perform the filtering, which they both support.  OpenLayers is a good choice for the front-end web map layer.

Other choices for map/data server are GeoServer and MapServer.